# Databricks 6.1 no database named global_temp error when initializing metastore connection

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

When initializing hive metastore connection (saving data frame as a table for the first time ) on cluster 6.1 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11) (Azure), I can see health check for database global_temp failing with the error:

```
20/02/18 12:11:17 INFO HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 0.13.0 using file:
...
20/02/18 12:11:21 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_database: global_temp
20/02/18 12:11:21 INFO audit: ugi=root  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: global_temp   
20/02/18 12:11:21 ERROR RetryingHMSHandler: NoSuchObjectException(message:There is no database named global_temp)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getMDatabase(ObjectStore.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDatabase(ObjectStore.java:498)
...
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:430)
...
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This doesn't cause python script to fail, but pollutes logs.

Shouldn't the global_temp database be automatically created?
Can the check be switched off? or the error suppressed?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am experiencing the same :(

Comment: Sorry @JarroVGIT, no solution so far. For the time being just ignoring this.